# php form, on submit post to two db tables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have a custom form that utilizes the code below. I have recently changed my DB set up to contain a customers table and a reservations table instead of it all being inside the same table. With this new set up I need to post to both the customers table - where the customer data lives, and the reservations table itself with the booking information.

I am unsure how to post to both tables using my already set up format below. I have updated the code as I thought it might go but have hit a wall and stumbling block since it is not working. What would be the way to fix this?

```
function booking_form() {           
    global $wpdb;   
    $table = "Customers";       
    $Customer_First_Name = $_POST['Customer_First_Name'];   
    $Customer_Last_Name = $_POST['Customer_Last_Name']; 
    $Customer_Number = $_POST['Customer_First_Name'];   
    $Customer_Email = $_POST['Customer_Email'];         
    $cdata = array(
    'Customer_First_Name' => $Customer_FName,
    'Customer_Last_Name' => $Customer_Last_Name,    
    'phone' => $Customer_Number,        
    'email' => $Customer_Email  );  
    $table = "reservations";
    $party_size = $_POST['party_size'];
    $rdata = array(
    'party_size' => $party_size,        
);
    
    $success = $wpdb->insert ignore( $table, $cdata );  
    $success = $wpdb->insert ignore( $table, $rdata );  
    $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id; $last_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mytablename WHERE wait_id = $id");           
    if($success)
    {echo json_encode($last_data);} 
    else{       echo 'error';   }   die;            
}
```

Comment: What is the schema? how do the tables relate?  But to make an educated guess, upsert into customers table, get last id, and then insert that customer id into the reservation table, along with whatever other info the reservation needs. But on further reflection it looks like your problem is with making the first query?

Comment: Thanks. It is with whether or not the above set up will work or if I need to start from scratch on it and treat them individually? IE post then a check then a return

Comment: I personally would make a function for each table, with `booking_form()` calling each of them. FWIW, you should inject (pass) values into functions rather than use globals. Your first function would return the last insert id, and `booking_form()` would call the next function and pass the customer id to it.

Comment: So my answer is that this is definitely the time to refactor!

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you want to suggest an example as an answer I can accept it for you!

Comment: thanks, but I don’t have near enough information about your table schema, and I’m not familiar enough with wordpress’ pseudo prepare method...